# How to scroll to show a part of a webpage

Tags: javascript, dynamic, scroll, browser

What are the different ways you can control/read the Scrollbar in a web browser with *JavaScript*, apart from anchors? -- Unless you can dynamically create anchors and tell the browser to scroll down to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To scroll by an arbitrary amount:

```
//Parameters being the amount by which to scroll in pixels (horizontal and vertical)
window.scrollBy(50, 50);
```

To scroll to a certain point:

```
 window.scrollTo(0, 30);
```

To read current position:

```
 document.body.scrollLeft
 document.body.scrollTop
```

Comment: I think you mean document.documentElement (normally refers to the <HTML> tag) instead of document.body.

Comment: No, the support of documentelement in IE is almost non-existent.

Comment: http://www.softcomplex.com/docs/get_window_size_and_scrollbar_position.html

Both are wrong depending on the browser, or are right. It's a bit of guesswork.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is one example](http://www.sitepoint.com/article/preserve-page-scroll-position/) of how you can control X/Y scrolling without anchors.  ( ScrollX/ScrollY)

The key part I suppose is the following

```
function saveScrollCoordinates() { 
  document.Form1.scrollx.value = (document.all)?document.body.scrollLeft:window.pageXOffset; 
  document.Form1.scrolly.value = (document.all)?document.body.scrollTop:window.pageYOffset; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the **`scrollTop`** property (inherent of all elements) you can scroll to a specific pixel height. So, scrolling to the height of a specific anchor would involve querying for the offset of that anchor and setting **`scrollTop`** accordingly. Just for illustration's sake; this is how you would scroll to a specified element with jQuery:

```
var top = $('div#something').offset().top;
$(document).scrollTop(top);
```

**NOTE**: jQuery's implementation can be misleading; it accepts **`document`** but the top-most element with the **`scrollTop`** property is, in fact, **`document.documentElement`** (usually refers to **`<HTML>`**).

There is also a **`scrollLeft`** property for horizontal scrolling.

And of course, you can read these properties:

```
var currentScrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
```

Answer (score 1):

Prototype [implements](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/scrollto) a `scrollTo()` function that makes it really easy to scroll to a particular element:

```
$("#elementID").scrollTo();
```

The implementation internally calls `window.scrollTo` to do the actual scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

```
var coord = {top:null,left:null,width:null,height:null};
        if (typeof window.pageYOffset == 'number') {
            coord.top = window.pageYOffset; coord.left = window.pageXOffset;            
        } else if (document.body && (document.body.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollTop)) {
            coord.top = document.body.scrollTop; coord.left = document.body.scrollLeft;
        } else if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollTop)) {
            coord.top = document.documentElement.scrollTop; coord.left = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        }

        if (typeof window.innerWidth == 'number') {
            coord.width = window.innerWidth; coord.height = window.innerHeight;
        } else if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {
            coord.width = document.documentElement.clientWidth; coord.height = document.documentElement.clienthHeight; 
        } else if(document.body && (document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight)) {
            coord.width = document.body.clientWidth;
            coord.height = document.body.clientHeight;
        }
```